# change image source on click event and add pixel

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change one image source with id using javascript, also I would like to add/remove width to the picture depending on whether we click on + or - button.

```js
var changeimg = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.src == "images/soleil.jpg") {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/eclipse.jpg";
  } else {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/soleil.jpg";
  }
}
var addpx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width <= "500") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.style.width + "20px"
  }
}
var removepx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width >= "250") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.style.width - "20px"
  }
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  sun_to_eclipse.addEventListener("click", changeimg);
  
  plus.addEventListener("click", addpx);
  minus.addEventListener("click", removepx);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setupListeners);
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="plus">+</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
  </div>
  <img id="sun" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/641353910561566720/VSxsyxs7_400x400.jpg" alt="sunny" />
</div>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: you haven't assigned `onclick` on your buttons.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh there are eventlistensers assigned in the js

Comment: Correct, sorry I skipped that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your setting widths. style.width will return text with some number plus the unit at the end. use offsetWidth property.

```js
var sun = false;
var changeimg = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  if (sun == false) {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/eclipse.jpg";
    sun = true;
  } else {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/soleil.jpg";
    sun = false;
  }
}
var addpx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width <= "500") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.offsetWidth + 20 + "px"
  }
}
var removepx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width >= "250") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.offsetWidth - 20 + "px"
  }
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  sun_to_eclipse.addEventListener("click", changeimg);
  
  plus.addEventListener("click", addpx);
  minus.addEventListener("click", removepx);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setupListeners);
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="plus">+</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
  </div>
  <img id="sun" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/641353910561566720/VSxsyxs7_400x400.jpg" alt="sunny" />
</div>
```

IMAGE ONCLICK: its not working properly because img.src contains the full address to the image. eg

```
document.getElementById("sun").src;
"file:///C:/Users/Abhinav/Desktop/images/soleil.jpg"
```

you can fix that using a variable

```
var sun = false;
var changeimg = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  if (sun == false) {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/eclipse.jpg";
    sun = true;
  } else {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/soleil.jpg";
    sun = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Also do you have any idea what to do to fix the click event on the img?

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

> To Fetch the Width use `.clientWidth` instead of `.style.width`

So for addpx use `sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth + 20 + "px";` and

for minus use `sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth - 20 + "px";`

```js
var changeimg = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  if (sun_to_eclipse.src == "https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e9c5fe6cb160f55f564723b8c1679170c74f5e53/687474703a2f2f73392e706f7374696d672e6f72672f7a336e707077797a332f73686565705f333530782e6a7067") {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "http://www.ptahai.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg";
  } else {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "https://camo.githubusercontent.com/e9c5fe6cb160f55f564723b8c1679170c74f5e53/687474703a2f2f73392e706f7374696d672e6f72672f7a336e707077797a332f73686565705f333530782e6a7067";
  }
}


var addpx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  if (sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth <= "500") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth + 20 + "px";
  }
}
var removepx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  if (sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth >= "250") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.clientWidth - 20 + "px";
  }
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");

  sun_to_eclipse.addEventListener("click", changeimg);

  plus.addEventListener("click", addpx);
  minus.addEventListener("click", removepx);
}

window.addEventListener("click", setupListeners);
```

```css
#sun {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="plus">+</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
  </div>
  <img id="sun" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028_1280.jpg" alt="sunny" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you vm! but the minus doesn't seem to work because I want a maximum of 500px and a minimum of 250px so when I press plus once and then minus once, it should go back to initial width but it's not the case

Comment: I did put the constrains back, I was just playing with your code. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Making use of **offsetWidth** to achieve this.

```js
var changeimg = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.src == "images/soleil.jpg") {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/eclipse.jpg";
  } else {
    sun_to_eclipse.src = "images/soleil.jpg";
  }
}
var addpx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width <= "500") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.offsetWidth + 20 + "px"
  }
}
var removepx = function() {
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  if (sun_to_eclipse.width >= "250") {
    sun_to_eclipse.style.width = sun_to_eclipse.offsetWidth - 20 + "px"
  }
}

var setupListeners = function() {
  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  var sun_to_eclipse = document.getElementById("sun");
  
  sun_to_eclipse.addEventListener("click", changeimg);
  
  plus.addEventListener("click", addpx);
  minus.addEventListener("click", removepx);
}

window.addEventListener("load", setupListeners);
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="plus" onClick =>+</button>
    <button id="minus">-</button>
  </div>
  <img id="sun" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/641353910561566720/VSxsyxs7_400x400.jpg" alt="sunny" />
</div>
```